# How Repeat backgroundWorker_DoWork After backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted In Code Behind?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, backgroundworker, windows

There is a button like below :

```
   private void btnStartAdventure_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker5.IsBusy)
        {
            btnStartAdventures.Enabled = false;
            lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Canceling...";
            backgroundWorker5.CancelAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            txtLogInAdventures.Text = string.Empty;
            btnStartAdventures.Text = "Cancel";
            lblUsersDoneCountValueInAdventures.Text = "---";
            lblStatusValueInAdventures.Text = "Running...";


            backgroundWorker5.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

i want to call `btnStartAdventure_Click` event again after `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` job!
so there will be a loop that never ends.
i put:

```
Thread.Sleep(3600000);
```

at the end of `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted()`.
now what code should i use for call `btnStartAdventure_Click` again?
is Timer good for my purpose or not?
how can i prevent hanging and crashes by doing that job?

thanks in advance

Comment: Just use a Timer.  Move the code in the Click event handler to a separate method that you can call from the timer's Tick event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fire the `btnStartAdventure_Click` event handler programmatically, you can call

```
// Call the Click event of btnStartAdventure.
btnStartAdventure.PerformClick();
```

Just put that code in the end of the `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` event.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkkb40tf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article for more information.

Comment: PerformClick will do the job but is' not a good practice. Better to refactor out the impl code to a separate method you can call from both places.

Comment: It won't do the job, you can't start a BGW that is still busy.

Comment: Right, a bgw is still 'Busy' during its Completed. Still possible to assign a new Bgw to backgroundWorker5 each time. I'd rather skip the Timer.